# Por que declarar static para todos os métodos de uma classe static?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, static

Eu estava estudando aqui C# até que cheguei na parte que fala sobre o `static`. O professor mostra que é possível utilizar essa declaração em métodos e até na própria classe.

O problema é que quando se utiliza o `static` na classe, todos os métodos devem ser declarados como `static` obrigatoriamente. A minha dúvida é: porque devo declarar `static` em todos os métodos se eu já declaro que a classe é estática?

Por que o compilador não pode simplesmente definir os métodos como estáticos implicitamente ao declarar a classe como estática, para que não precise adicionar essa declaração a dezenas de métodos e atributos como no exemplo abaixo?

```
static class Class1 {
    static public void Method1(){...}
    static public void Method2(){...}
    static public void Method3(){...}
}

// Bem melhor a forma abaixo não é ?

static class Class2 {
    public void Method1(){...}
    public void Method2(){...}
    public void Method3(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E por que você deveria deixar de dizer que o método estático é estático?

É uma questão de gosto. Você acha que digitar menos é mais importante, os criadores da linguagem acharam que era mais importante ser mais legível e consistente. Se o método é estático diga que ele é estático, em outras classes e interface tem que dizer, diga nessa também.

O compilador poderia aceitar isso, não há motivos técnicos que impeçam, mas linguagem tem estética e preferiram assim.

Mas há dúvidas qual é a melhor forma. Um dos escritores do compilador do C# diz como é difícil decidir o que é melhor fazer, traduzo aqui a [resposta do Eric Lippert no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005213/221800):

> Eu recebo perguntas como essa o tempo todo. Basicamente, a pergunta se resume a "quando de fato um membro declarado pode ser deduzido pelo compilador, a declaração explícita desse fato deve ser (1) obrigatória, (2) opcional ou (3) proibida?"
>
> Não há uma resposta fácil. Cada uma deve ser tomada caso a caso. É
> necessário colocar `static` em um membro de uma classe estática.
> Colocar `new` em um método oculto e não substituinte de uma classe
> derivada é opcional. É proibido colocar `static` em uma `const`.
>
> Considerando brevemente seu cenário, parece bizarro torná-lo proibido.
> Você tem uma classe inteira cheia de métodos marcados como `static`.
> Você decide tornar a classe estática e isso significa que você deve
> remover todos os modificadores estáticos? Isso seria estranho.
>
> Parece bizarro torná-lo opcional; suponha que você tenha uma classe
> estática e dois métodos, um marcado como estático e outro não. Como a
> estática normalmente não é o padrão, parece natural pensar que existe
> uma diferença entre eles. Torná-lo opcional parece ser potencialmente
> confuso.
>
> Isso faz com que ser obrigatório, como a menos ruim das três opções.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).